# Dataset for sentiment analysis of diary entries

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, dataset, word2vec

I was wondering if there is a dataset of sentiment-labelled diary entries? What I am looking for is a table of diary entries and a label indicating at least whether the entry is "positive" or "negative" (or even classified into more categories).

Example (completely arbitrary):

- "Today the floor was icy, I slipped and fell. I hate ice." *=> label:
  "negative"*
- "I love my friends! They organised a surprise party for
  me!" *=> label: "positive"*

Answer (score 1):

I have found this data set on kaggle.I hope this would be helpful                        **https://www.kaggle.com/c/si650winter11/data**.                                          In this data set **1** represents **positive** and **0** represents **negative**

Comment: Thank you, it's interesting. It's rather small and has many duplicates, but it's still useful!